# How to fix Python error importing ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml

I'm beginning to learn python and here I'm trying to read from an xml file using ElementTree:

```
import sys
from elementtree.ElementTree import ElementTree

doc = ElementTree(file="test.xml")
doc.write(sys.stdout)
```

However I get this error:
 File "my_xml.py", line 2, in 
    from elementtree.ElementTree import ElementTree
ImportError: No module named elementtree.ElementTree

I do have lib files in /usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/...
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
```

More information on this can be found at the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).